# Deploy .NET Core Console App to Windows VM using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, console-application, continuous-deployment

We have a .NET Core Console App which we publish to an On Prem VM using publish feature in Visual Studio.  Here is how we configure publishing to a file system.

Target location in the image is actually the folder structure of where we want our app to reside on the VM.

[image]

How can we configure the same in DevOps.  I can't seem to find any good resource on this.

I have created a CI build pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps to deploy Console App to the On Prem VM.

1, Create a deployment agent on On-Prem VM. create a deployment group from azure devops portal. Follow the first part of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@samjwright/automating-deployments-to-on-premis-servers-with-azure-devops-bb0e6cac4656) to create deployment group. Check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) for more information about deployment group.

2, Create a release pipeline. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops).

- Setup the artifacts(you should have the [publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task in the CI build pipeline to publish the console app build artifacts to azure devops server.), and add stage for the release pipeline.
- Add a deployment group job in the release stage.

[image]

- see below screenshot to select the deployment group created in the first step, which contains the deployment agent on the ON-premise VM,
- Add [copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the console app build artifacts to the folder on the ON-premise VM

[image]

[image]

Another workaround is to use self-hosted agent(steps are similar to above using deployment group). Check the detailed steps in [this example](http://kannekens.nl/how-to-set-up-a-local-deployment-for-an-azure-build-application/).

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know